# Reading Excel File using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am new to C# and I am trying to read an excel file with the following code

```
string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFilePath + 
                ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);
    using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var row1Col0 = dr[0];
            Console.WriteLine(row1Col0);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Sheet1$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

Can anyone tell me whats I am doing wrong?

The name of excel sheet is sheet.xlsx

[image]
Thanks

Comment: That's the name of the file. What are the names on the tabs inside the file? IIRC that's what the sheets are.

Comment: I attached the image of the excel sheet

Comment: What's the name of the tab at the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: contents is the name there

Comment: Then that is the sheet name. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The sheet name might not be the same as the filename, you can get the first sheet name by doing the following

First, get the schema

```
DataTable dtSchema = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
```

Then get the first sheets name

```
var sheetName = dtSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
```

After you get your `command`, you can then fill a dataset and work with it's `.Rows` collection

```
var myDataSet = new DataSet();
command.Fill(myDataSet);
```

The sheetname is this
[image]

Comment: I'd put the data in a dataset with `command.Fill` then work with the dataset like normal

Comment: Can you please provide some psudocode I am very new to C#